# How to read call logs or call history in react native ios device?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I was trying to read call logs from android and ios both, for android I was able to get the call logs using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-call-log but for ios I am unable to do because it is only available for Android.

I have tried searching for the solution everywhere but there is no library created for ios. I also found an answer on StackOverflow where someone created his own library using java and bind it. I don't know java, 
Is there any way I can read ios call logs using javascript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only get state of Call like incoming and outgoing. But you can’t get call log because of the Security concern.  Apple don’t allow to access its application to third party app like call log and messages.

Comment: Thank you, then there is no way to get call logs maybe thats why there are no libraries are made for ios devices.

Comment: @vinny, can you clarify what you mean? You can get the state of the call (incoming, outgoing) , do you mean currently incoming or outgoing or is this incoming/outgoing for last x number off phone calls? Also, can you get the phone number of those calls?